# Devise + omniauth + carrierwave doesn't save facebook profile image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, omniauth, carrierwave

I am using devise with omniauth facebook. I upload avatars for people that are not signing in with facebook with carrierwave, with the AvatarUploader.

But when I try fetching the avatar from the facebook user, it does not save - `user.avatar = auth.info.image` does not save, and after signing in equals `nil`.

Why is that and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.avatar = auth.info.image
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried [this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#uploading-files-from-a-remote-location)?

In your method, change the line

```
user.avatar = auth.info.image
```

to

```
user.remote_avatar_url = auth.info.image
```